# Achieve a two column table look with CSS/Divs

Tags: css, html

I need a two column table with one word in the left column (e.g. name, biography) and with details for each in the right column. I have tried:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left_column">......</div>
<div id="right_column">......</div>
```

`</div>`

This looks fine if the right column only has one or two words, but for longer entries such as 'bio' the second div's info snakes underneath the left_column div.

What's the easiest way to achieve the two columns without this happening?

Comment: I'm not one to use tables for layout purposes, but what you describe for content would probably be better served (from a semantic POV) in a table using `<th scope="row">` for the name and '<td>` for the details. Putting it in generic divs will actually be counterproductive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to float them, and set some widths.

```
#container {
    width:100%;
}
#left_column {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}
#right_column {
    float:left;
    width:80%;
}
```

Note: If you only float them, and don't set widths, they'll still snake under each other when the browser window gets narrow.

Comment: You can also use fixed widths if you prefer, as long as the sum of the columns equals the container.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property to make it a floating element and display:inline-block doesn't work on all browsers.

```
float:left;
```

You could also you `<span>` which by default won't wrap.